# Module Isomorphism from Z4 to Z2+Z2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to find the module isomorphisms from $Z_4 $ to $ Z_2 \oplus Z_2$

I understand it has to map the zero element to zero element. But after that I don't know what to do. Also I understand this problem can be viewed as finding the group isomorhpisms.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which isomorphism you're looking for, but $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ are not isomorphic as groups since the former contains an element of order $4$ while the latter does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such isomorphism, as all elements in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ have order $\le 2$, and $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ has a generator of order $4$.